# Is compression a linear operation?

Tags: io, compression

I'm mincing terms here but I think its the most concise was to ask it.

When I say linear, I mean linear as in like a linear operation in mathematics i.e. `f(t+p) = f(t)+f(p)`.

At work, we have datasets we store in `.h5` files. We do this for space reasons. When we perform data analysis and post processing, we have to open the `.h5` file and grab data. Due to the way our system has been set up, we unfortunately end up opening up that `.h5` file multiple times, grabbing just a small subset of the tables each time. This is hard on our file system and causes obvious run time performance of the scripts, and the network in general.

I wonder if it would be better to not store all the tables in a single `.h5` file. Perhaps chunk it up into smaller ones, or even compress each table individually, that way when a script only needs to access a small set of tables it doesn't take so long.

I am curious if this would come with a trade off, i.e. would we lose space by compressing individually? Which is why I titled this post the way I did. If the act of compressing a file is linear, then compressing the tables individually should sum up to the same as compressing a single file holding all the tables.

I of course doubt that compression is linear, but just how much of a difference in storage utilization could occur?

Comment: What kind of compression?

Comment: Depends on algorithm, the data, how big chunks you want, etc... For anything non-trivial, it's unlikely to be linear as you describe. In general, I'd expect some trade-off between granularity and compression effectiveness. Your best bet is to make a prototype that fits your use-case and benchmark it.

Comment: we use h5 compression?

Comment: I haven't used HDF5, but looking at the documentation, it supports a number of different compression filters -- which particular one do you use? What's the rough size of the subset you grab at a time?

Comment: For illustration: From my own experience with a [IFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_File_Format) inspired file format I wrote over a decade ago and that we still use.... It allows compression of either individual measurements (~800 bytes in this case) or groups of them (for this 1 minute groups were adequate). Using zlib, with level 6 here. Raw file is 95 MB. Compressing the whole thing gives me 50.2MB. Writing it so that each 1 minute chunk is compressed independently gives me 50.5MB. Writing it so that each measurement is compressed independently gives me 74MB.

Comment: .. (Oh, the file holds 1 hour) ... On the other hand, compressing the whole thing with BZip2 yields ~30MB, and doing it in one minute groups is quite similar. However using it to compress all those relatively tiny measurements give 82MB and horrible time performance. Other compression methods have different trade-offs. As I've suggested before (from my own experience) it's best to just try out the possibilities yourself. | From what I've seen, if you're reading something like MB at a time (and you care about speed), compressing each "chunk" separately won't incur significant storage overhead.